# Workarounds for :visited CSS History reconnaissance

Tags: web-browser, privacy, html

Several years ago it was possible to use

```
a:visited {
   background: url('/log.php');
}
```

to figure out on what website user has been previously. But now it is restricted by browsers. Is there any other way to know which websites user have been recently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is still possible.  However, it is much harder to do unobtrusively now.  See the following research paper for details of how to do it:

- [I Still Know What You Visited Last Summer: Leaking browsing history via user interaction and side channel attacks](https://www.ieee-security.org/TC/SP2011/PAPERS/2011/paper010.pdf), Zack Weinberg, Eric Chen, Pavithra Ramesh Jayaraman, and Collin Jackson, IEEE Security and Privacy Symposium 2011.

Please do not use this to spy on visitors to your web site without their consent.  That has the potential to be a bad business move.

We've been through this before.  The last time some web sites tried using CSS history sniffing, they eventually got caught.  The fact that they were using history sniffing got into the news, and caught the attention of the FTC and many others.  Lawsuits were filed, and investigations were opened.  So I think we have solid evidence that if you history-sniff your visitors, you are asking for trouble.  For more information on this, see the following sources:

- [NAI To Probe Epic Marketplace's 'History-Sniffing' Techniques](http://www.mediapost.com/publications/article/154545/nai-to-probe-epic-marketplaces-history-sniffing.html).
- [Suit to Snuff Out 'History Sniffing' Takes Aim at Tracking Web Users](http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10001424052748704493004576001622828777658.html).  Note the quote from the FTC official.  It's not good when the FTC is willing to make a public statement expressing concerns over your business practices.
- [The FTC Promises an End to History Sniffing (Microsoft, Take Note)](http://www.forbes.com/sites/kashmirhill/2010/12/09/the-ftc-promises-an-end-to-history-sniffing-microsoft-take-note/?boxes=Homepagelighttop).
- [Browser History Sniffing in the News](https://www.cdt.org/blogs/justin-brookman/browser-history-sniffing-news).  Excerpt: "Clearly, companies know it’s a bad practice to sniff browser history. In fact, it’s probably illegal too."
- [History Sniffing](http://www.drm.com/news/2011/03/22/history-sniffing/)
- The research paper that kicked off all of this: [An Empirical Study of Privacy-Violating Information Flows in JavaScript Web Applications](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~hovav/dist/history.pdf), Dongseok Jang, Ranjit Jhala, Sorin Lerner, and Hovav Shacham, ACM CCS 2010.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite possible. The trick they've used to prevent this attack involves disabling CSS on the `:visited` selector. However, that doesn't stop the selector from still being there!

You can use JavaScript to iterate through a set of links, checking for the `:visited` selector on each. It's possible to do the check using [`cssRules`](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/externalcss3.shtml), which should tell you which rules are being applied to a DOM element. Once you've found the visited ones, you can do an Ajax post back onto the site to store the results. There's a [proof of concept](http://www.gnucitizen.org/blog/javascript-visited-link-scanner/) of this trick, though there's no guarantee of it being correct and functional across all browsers.

Comment: I'm confused. That POC is from 2006 and is simply a POC of the no-longer-possible attack described in the question here (where you check the color of a link using `getComputedStyle` and from that infer whether it was matched by a `:visited` selector). It doesn't use `cssRules`. Nor does the `CSSRule` interface appear to offer any means of getting a list of all elements matching the rule. Am I getting something wrong, or is everything written here nonsense, as it seems to me?

Comment: I wrote this 7 years ago, and I honestly have no idea. It does look like the PoC I linked doesn't use `cssRules` like I thought it did; it's possible it was changed after I linked it, but I could've just misunderstood. Anyway, if you'd like a newer approach, check out the [history stealing timing attack](https://antoinevastel.com/security/privacy/2017/04/09/history-stealing.html) which utilises animation timers to detect whether a CSS shadow was applied or not.

Comment: That approach too has been at least mitigated by reducing the precision of all timestamps that the browser reports to JavaScript.